# Definition of Oxidation

Tags: redox

Most textbooks define "Gain of Oxygen" as oxidation. Why the gain of Fluorine is not included as part of the definitions since Fluorine is more electronegative than Oxygen?

Comment: Your statement is completely incorrect. Oxidation is all about change of oxidation state, not specific elements.

Comment: There is more than one meaning of "oxidation", just as a mole can be a small furry creature, and "organic" food is not defined fro m *organic* chemistry (and "organic meat" referred to viscera).

Comment: Most _chemistry_ textbooks don't define oxidation like that.

Comment: Please wait for next week's lecture, or check the next two pages of your textbook. It is surely going to introduce a more refined definition of oxidation. If not, get a new textbook, or a new teacher.

Comment: See also [IUPAC Goldbook](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/O04362) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redox)

Comment: Gain of oxygen is the 19th century definition of the word "oxidation". Today it has been generalized to an increase in the oxidation number, which can be done by oxygen, or by some other reagent.